# Is the 555 timer output always V+ or ground?

Tags: timer, 555, floating

If the output of the 555 timer is not trigger to high, is it ground? Or is the output left floating?

Comment: You can find a schematic on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC) which shows two versions. Both have a push-pull end stage. So the output is high or low, but is never left floating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice question. It would be helpful to know the exact part number of the 555 timer you are using (every vendor has one by this point).

However, we can still address this question. The output will either be a push-pull output, or an open-drain output.

A push-pull output will always have the output at either HIGH or LOW. It does this with a complementary pair of FETs in the output stage.

Open-drain devices only have one FET in the output stage. This FET is between the output and ground, and therefore can only pull the output LOW. When the output needs to go HIGH, this FET turns off and you must have an external pull up resistor between the output and VDD to get a HIGH output.

Push-pulls are what you will normally find, like in this TI [TLC555](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc555.pdf). However, open-drain is useful when you want the logic level of the output signal to be different than the VDD of the 555 timer. This is done by connecting the pull up resistor to whichever voltage level you want the output to be. (Just make sure you aren't exceeding the voltage rating of the output pin!)

[image]

Comment: Isn't your open-drain configuration what's on the DISCHARGE pin of the 555?

Comment: @Scott Seidman While it is the same circuitry (which is a stretch of the word since this is only one FET), but we should think about it a little differently.

Open-Drain is an output used for pulling an OUT pin to a logic LOW voltage (usually ground).
The discharge pin on a 555 is used to sink current, discharging a capacitor.

Just two of the many, many ways you can use a FET :)

Comment: If you put 555 as type on the chip it has to be compatible so it *must* have a push-pull output. Therefore I do not agree with you saying it can be open collector/open drain.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be acceptable to flip the connection for GND and VCC if I want ground to be the triggered output condition? Or, would it be better practice to invert the signal some other way? Or, would this not actually change anything?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you want to swap power and ground and then expect the chip to work in reverse? That would be like putting a car on it's roof and expect to have 4 reverse gears,  but all that gets you is a damaged car. Likewise swapping power and ground only gives you a burned out chip.

Comment: I figured it wouldn't work, it was just a question. I've used relays plenty of times to switch power and ground. Was wondering if this would work the same way.

Comment: @Oldfart: I don't know every 555 chip in existence, so I decided to cover my bases and discuss both push-pull and open-drain options. It seemed relevant since Alex was curious if his output could be floating. I don't think there is any governing body that enforces that all 555 chips be push-pull. That said I agree with your sentiment that it's most likely going to be push-pull.

Comment: @AlexMarks
While I agree with Oldfart that you will not be able to swap power and ground on your 555 timer, I do encourage this type of outside the box thinking.
For example, if you take a buck converter and swap VOUT and GND, you end up with an inverting buck-boost converter. Doesn't sound intuitive at first, but sometimes a little crazy thinking pays off :)